# C++ concepts and conversion issue

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

In the following example:

```
#include <concepts>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

integral auto multiply(integral auto p_val_1, integral auto p_val_2) {
  return p_val_1 * p_val_2;
}

int main() {
  {
    float f{multiply(4, 3)};
    cout << "f = " << f << endl;
  }

  {
    float f(multiply(4, 3));
    cout << "f = " << f << endl;
  }

  {
    constexpr uint16_t i1{4};
    constexpr uint16_t i2{3};
    float f{multiply(i1, i2)};
    cout << "f = " << f << endl;
  }

  {
    constexpr int i1{4};
    constexpr int i2{3};
    float f(multiply(i1, i2));
    cout << "f = " << f << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

`gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0`, in `float f{multiply(4, 3)};`, reports

```
main.cpp:13:13: Non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'int' to 'float' in initializer list (fix available)
insert an explicit cast to silence this issue
```

and in `float f{multiply(i1, i2)};`, it reports

```
main.cpp:25:13: Non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'int' to 'float' in initializer list (fix available)
insert an explicit cast to silence this issue
```

In my (still) poor understanding of concepts, it should not be possible to assign the result of `multiply` to an object that would not satisfy the `std::integral` requirement, but using `float f(multiply(i1, i2));` or `float f(multiply(4, 3));` it is.

Would anyone be kind to explain why?

Comment: "_In my (still) poor understanding of concepts, it should not be possible to assign the result of multiply to an object that would not satisfy the std::integral requirement_": Based on what are source are you making this assumption? (It is wrong.)

Comment: On your platform (and mine), an `int` **narrows** to fit into a `float`.  You are using the syntax with the `{}` to indicate that you do not want narrowing to occur.

Comment: It is my understanding that since I am defining that the return value of `multiply` must satisfy `std::integral`, so the object that to which this return will be assigned should also satisfy `std::integral`. 

If this understanding is wrong, can I conclude that there is no point in defining a restriction (requirement) for the return of a function, since the object that will receive the value does not need to satisfy the same requirements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only effect of putting a concept constraint on `auto` in the return type is that the program will fail to compile if `auto` is deduced to something that doesn't satisfy the concept. It has no other effect besides that.

In your example `multiply(4, 3)` deduces the parameter types of `multiply` both to `int` and so `p_val_1 * p_val_2` is also of type `int` and the return type is deduced to `int`. `int` satisfies `std::integral`, so the concept check is satisfied.

That you are then converting the `int` result of `multiply(4, 3)` to something else is completely unaffected by the concept constraint on the return type or the function at all.

---

The conversion is ill-formed with braces because initialization with braces doesn't allow narrowing conversions, which integral-to-floating-point conversions always are, except if the source expression is a constant expression with a value that can be represented exactly in the target type. In none of your cases is it a constant expression, because `multiply` is not marked `constexpr` or `consteval`.

Aside from that any integral type is however implicitly convertible to any floating-point type. So with any other initialization syntax the program is well-formed.

All of this is completely independent of the constraint on the return type of `multiply`.

Comment: "That you are then converting the int result of multiply(4, 3) to something else is completely unaffected by the concept constraint on the return type." 

That is my error: I thought that by defining a restriction to the return of `multiply` would force the object to receive the return to adhere to the same restriction.

Comment: @canellas There are 3 sometimes distinct objects in `Result result = function()` return path.  (1) The object `result`, (2) the object within `function` which is returned, and (3) the object returned from `function`.  Elision can reduce this to 1 object, but if they are distinct types won't occur.  And your restriction applies only to (3); with `auto` however it is then deduced from (2) and identical to it and hence elided into one object.